# How to maintain a single dockerfile for all the environments for react js?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the written the following `Dockerfile` after looking at lots of implementation for react with multi stage builds. I am trying to achieve to have a single Dockerfile for all the environments. Currently dev + prod but in future, dev, qa, automation, staging, pt, preprod, prod.

```
# Create a base image with dependencies
FROM node:16.15.0-alpine3.14 AS base
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./



# Create a development environment
FROM base AS development
ENV NODE_ENV development

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]


# Generate build
FROM base AS builder
ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN yarn install --production
COPY . .

RUN yarn build


# Create a production image
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine as production

ENV NODE_ENV production
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/htm
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

So I have a couple of questions as below,

1. In the above `Dockerfile` when I target `production` in my `docker-compose.yml` file will it run the development stage as well in the Dockerfile?
2. If so how can I avoid it being run? Because the development has a different `yarn install` command ad it also copies the src folder which will be redundant in `production` stage.
3. Should I strive to have a single Dockerfile and multiple `docker-compose.yml` files like `docker-compose.dev.yml`, `docker-compose.prod.yml` etc?

Comment: Why would the _container_ be different between environments? You should have one production build artefact that you _promote_ between environments, supplying the necessary config as e.g. env vars.

Comment: @jonrsharpe for automation I will be installing npm packages like cypress that will not be used for any of the prod env.  Also do you know the answer for question 1 & 2 that will clear up a lot of things for me?

Comment: Why would they be in the production container? If you insist on a containerised dev environment then manage that separately, every other environment should be using a consistent artefact. Otherwise there's no point e.g. running your Cypress tests on the "automation" image, because that's not what's actually going to be used.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So for dev env I have to create a separate Dockerfile.dev? 
When you say consistent artifact you mean I have to use the same prod build for testing, and all higher environments? except dev? If so since we wont be installing dev dependencies for prod artifacts how will cypress package work on that build?

Comment: I would suggest that, or just use a local dev environemnt. And Cypress would work from _outside_ the actual app container - running in its own container (they maintain several for you), for example. That means you're testing the actual artefact.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a base file docker-compose.yml which will contain the common services. you can then create docker-compose-prod.yml , docker-compose-dev.yml, etc. which contains environment specific overrides. While executing docker compose command, you can specify multiple files and the configuration will be merged and executed as single file.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

you can read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).